# Show div element when user inputs text in a different field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show a `div` element only whenever user inputs some text in a different field.

**Text Field:**

`<input type="text" id="feedUrl" placeholder="API"`

**Div:**

```
div class="col-xs-12 text-left" id="continue" style="display: none;">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top:30px;" id='continueNewFeed'>
        Continue
    </a>
</div>
```

**JaveScript:**

```
if($('feedUrl').val()){
    $('#continue').show(); 
}
```

The issue I am having is that the Continue div does not show up whenever I write in the `feedUrl` input.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your selector is wrong. Use `$('#feedUrl')`.

Comment: Do you have any listener on the input to detect changes?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I actually do not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a listener on the input to detect changes. Also modify the ID selector as @bukharim mentiond in comments to `$("#feedUrl")`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#feedUrl").on("input",function(){
    if($(this).val()){
        $('#continue').show(); 
    }
    else{
        $('#continue').hide(); 
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="feedUrl" placeholder="API">


<div class="col-xs-12 text-left" id="continue" style="display: none;">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top:30px;" id='continueNewFeed'>
        Continue
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The event `input` captures change, keyup, Etc, so you don't need to bind all of them.

Comment: Yep it works. Thanks! Any way I can get it back to hidden whenever user erases the input?

Comment: I have updated the answer to cover your recent comment.

Answer (score 2):

Bind the event `input` to capture changes from that input field and check for the entered value.

**Use this selector instead:**

```
$('#feedUrl')
```

```js
var $feedUrl = $('#feedUrl')
$feedUrl.on('input', function() {
  var $continue = $('#continue');
  if ($(this).val()) $continue.show();
  else $continue.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="feedUrl" placeholder="API">


<div class="col-xs-12 text-left" id="continue" style="display: none;">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top:30px;" id='continueNewFeed'>
        Continue
    </a>
</div>
```